# Zoom in not working on Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I took a Highmaps example from the demo section and zooming in was working fine. Then I replaced the data object with my own data and changed the world map with my own GeoJSON data.

Now the zoom doesn't work anymore.

Please see this **[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hz34r530/)**

I managed to simplify the code up to this point:

```
var geoJson = { ... }
var data = [...]

// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        navigationButtons: true
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        type: 'logarithmic'
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        mapData: geoJson,
        joinBy: ['name', 'name'],

    }]
});
```

What can I do to make the zoom work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a bug, it works if you change your coordinate data. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz34r530/4/):

```
var geoJson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "a"
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                [
                    [3125, 6250],
                    [5625, 6250],
                    [5624, 8750],
                    [3125, 8750],
                    [3125, 6250]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            "name": "b"
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                [
                    [6875, 6250],
                    [9375, 6250],
                    [9375, 8750],
                    [6875, 8750],
                    [6875, 6250]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
};

// Initiate the chart
$('#container').highcharts('Map', {

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
    },

    series: [{
        mapData: geoJson
    }]
});
```

I suggest [filing an issue](http://www.highcharts.com/support) on GitHub, and we'll look into it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it should do the trick for now. I logged this on github as an issue: **Highmaps zoom-in not working when coordinates are small values #3762**

Comment: Turns out this probably is due to the default settings of the xAxis/yAxis.minRange options, which limit zooming. The default is set to 5 times the smallest area. By setting these options lower, you can zoom in further. See the [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3762).

Comment: Thanks, the solution Pawelfus offered is great